# How to sort a list of strings containing numbers numerically

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

If i wanted a list that contains numbers and words, like this one

```
random_list=["h: 100", "g: 57", "k: 1", "p: 200"]
```

Sorted numerically so it becomes

```
["k: 1", "g: 57", "h: 100", "p: 200"]
```

What would be the code in python 3?

Comment: That's not a list, it's a dictionary.

Comment: That's not even a dictionary, it's a SyntaxError.

Comment: Well, true, it's dictionary-ish. Sort of. Not really...

Comment: @hello, why don't you post your code of what you are trying to do, what you want to accomplish and we can go from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python sorting allows for a `key` keyword that can be used to define your own sorting method.  The below code is for Python 2.7, I assume 3 is similar:

```
random_list=["h: 100", "g: 57", "k: 1", "p: 200"]

sorted(random_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))

#  ['k: 1', 'g: 57', 'h: 100', 'p: 200']
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that's a wrong data structure. You either mean a list or a dictionary.

Since the contents of your 'list' are key-value pairs, I'm guessing what you need is a dictionary instead. Dictionaries have the sorted() function available to them.